# Excel: If cell1 is empty then show "NA" in Cell2 else show dropdown with some options

Tags: excel

What i would like here is when my cell1(A1) value is null/empty then B1 should show "NA".but if A1 contains some value the B1 should show dropdow with options say major,Minor,Cosmetic etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add the "NA" also in the list of values to your drop down list. Then write this formula in cell B1 `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"N/A")`.
This is how I have done it in my end
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice.It works.but I cannot add NA in the drop down list as the sheet i am working on is created by management..so we cannot add any new categories..please suggest me something without adding NA in the list.